# Creating Class<?> objects where <?> is defined as a String in an ArrayList<String> - Java

Tags: java, generics, classloader

I have an array of String which correspond to the names of Classes in one of my packages.

For example, lets say I had an ArrayList that contained three items: "A1", "A2", "A3".

I would like to create instances of these classes using code such as:

```
    Class<?> objectToCreate = (Class<?>) MyStaticClass.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(objectToCreate);
    <?> objectCreated = objectToCreate.newInstance();
```

Such that, after looping through the above lines of code, I would have one instance of an A1 class, one instance of an A2 class, and one instance of an A3 class.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I realise this is "let me Google that for you" territory but I'm struggling to think of the noun to query that would give me the answer!

Comment: I have since revisited this after about 18 months. I see now that my question oversighted on the fundamentality that a collection with a generic contains 'like' types. The type in this case could have been a humble String, and using @alphazero's suggestion in the answers this could've been used to give birth to instances of the Type returned as a String. Thanks however and also to sblundy for the steer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `?` to be something other than a wildcard, meaning it has to be defined somewhere. Your options are on the method or the class. I expect method will work, so try wrapping this in a method, like so:

```
public <T> T create(String name) {
   Class<T> objectToCreate = (Class<T>) MyStaticClass.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(objectToCreate);
   T objectCreated = objectToCreate.newInstance();
   return objectCreated;
}
```

Comment: That's the problem I have, sblundy. I need "T" to be the same as the String coming out of the StringArray. Is there anyway to Cast to the value of a String?

Comment: @7SpecialGems: Yes, there has to be a cast at some point. You see, the String doesn't have a type associated with it, at least not from the compiler's perspective. The String's just a string.

Comment: Perhaps I've given a bad example - I'll try another: Class clazz = Class.forName(objectToCreate); Object obj = clazz.newInstance(); System.out.println("Type: " + obj.getClass().getName()); gives me the type of the class. However I need to downcast from Object to this value for the benefit of the Compiler, so that I can call a method specific to obj, not in Object, such as obj.someSpecificMethod().

Comment: @7SpecialGems: Yep, you still need to cast. The type of obj is simply not determinable to the compiler. That's both the benefit and cost of reflection.

Comment: @sblundy: fyi that form -- Foo f = create("foo") -- seems to work with some compilers and not others. Eclipse is happy but then maven build (on Mac OS X for ex) will complain about not knowing T.

Comment: @alphazero: I've noticed that too. Foo f = this.<Foo>create("Foo"); should be safe, but is no less verbose than a cast.

Comment: Sometimes that just about sums up my feeling about generics in Java: that is all it is doing for me at the end of day (obviating casts in most cases) and the cost equation for that paltry gain is pretty unappealing. (Thanks btw, I keep forgetting about that explicit call form.)

Comment: @sblundy: I hear you, but the core mechanism remains lexical in nature and scoped by compilation unit, right? Wouldn't that still room for some pain?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the class using

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classname);
```

You can certainly use `newInstance()` if your classes provide a public no-arg constructor.  Alternatively, you can get all available constructors and invoke the ctor with appropriate parameters.

Comment: Happy enough with Class clazz = Class.forName(className) and Object obj = clazz.newInstance(), but is there then any way to downcast from Object to the object type of the same name as the string "className" ?

Comment: It's not magic, right?  (As noted in your conv with sblundy) there isn't enough info to determine 'T' at compile time.  If you really have no info beyond the name of the class, then you need to get your hands dirty with some Byte Code Engineering or compile dynamically and gen the factory at runtime (with correct cast in the code you compile, etc.)